# Making Vivado Synthesis "A process triggered every clock cycle will not have functionality every clock cycle"

Tags: verilog, hdl, synthesis, vivado

This is code for ALU that does addition and multiplication only. An addition is handled in same clock cycle but the multiplication result has to be delayed by 3 clock cycles.

```
module my_addmul(
    //control signals
    input i_clk,
    input i_rst,
    input i_en,

    //add=01, mul=10
    input [1:0] i_op,

    //input and output registers
    input [31:0] i_A,
    input [31:0] i_B,
    output [31:0] o_D,

    //to signal if output is valid
    output o_done
    );


 //registers to save output
       reg [31:0] r_D;
       reg [63:0] r_mul;//(*keep="true"*)
       reg r_mul_done;
       reg r_mul_done2;
       reg r_done;

       //updating outputs
       assign o_D = r_D;
       assign o_done = r_done;


   always @ (posedge i_clk)    
   begin
       r_done <= 0;
       r_mul_done <= 0;

       if (i_rst) begin

           r_D <= 0;
           r_mul <= 0;
           r_mul_done <= 0;
           r_mul_done2 <= 0;

       end else if (i_clk == 1) begin

           if (i_en == 1) begin

               //addition - assignment directly to OP registers
               if (i_op == 01) begin
                   r_done <= 1;
                   r_D <= i_A + i_B;

               //multiplication - indirect assignment to OP registers
               end else if (i_op == 2'b10) begin
                   r_mul <= i_A * i_B;
                   r_mul_done <= 1;
               end
           end

           //1-clock cycle delay
           r_mul_done2 <= (r_mul_done == 1) ? 1 : 0;

           //updating outputs in the 3rd cycle
           if (r_mul_done2 == 1) begin
               r_D <= r_mul[31:0];
               r_done <= 1;
           end
       end
   end   
endmodule
```

The problem is that if the `keep` attribute is not used, the `r_mul` register that stores the multiplication output until 3rd clock cycle is optimised out. I read on the problem and realised that Vivado is thinking like this: "If the multiplication happens every clock cycle, the `r_mul` is over-written before it is sent to output. Therefore, it is a register being written but not read, Lets remove it!" Since I insert the 3 clock cycle wait in test bench, the simulation result is always accurate. I want to know what is the "Proper" way of doing this so I don't have to use the `keep` attribute. It is an ok solution but I think useful techniques should be learned so hacks don't have to be used. Any ideas or discussion welcome.

Comment: Probably not related to your immediate issue but you need to change `else if (i_clk == 1) begin` to `else begin`. Referencing an posedge/negedge signal inside an always block tends to confuse many synthesizers into thinking you wanted asynchronous latching behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I want to delay a signal, I'd probably insert flops for that. You can probably flop your `mul_output` like the way you do for the `mul_done` signal. Also, it is better to have different `always` blocks for doing the same. You can check the code below but it might be buggy since I haven't simulated/synthesized it -

```
module my_addmul(
    //control signals
    input i_clk,
    input i_rst,
    input i_en,

    //add=01, mul=10
    input [1:0] i_op,

    //input and output registers
    input [31:0] i_A,
    input [31:0] i_B,
    output [31:0] o_D,

    //to signal if output is valid
    output o_done
    );


 //registers to save output
       reg [31:0] r_D;
       reg [63:0] r_mul;//(*keep="true"*)
       reg r_mul_1;
       reg r_mul_2;
       reg r_mul_done;
       reg r_mul_done2;
       reg r_done;

       //updating outputs
       assign o_D = r_D;
       assign o_done = r_done;


   always @ (posedge i_clk)    
   begin
       r_done <= 0;
       r_mul_done <= 0;

       if (i_rst) begin

           r_D <= 0;
           r_mul <= 0;
           r_mul_done <= 0;
           r_mul_done2 <= 0;

       end else if (i_clk == 1) begin

           if (i_en == 1) begin

               //addition - assignment directly to OP registers
               if (i_op == 01) begin
                   r_done <= 1;
                   r_D <= i_A + i_B;

               //multiplication - indirect assignment to OP registers
               end else if (i_op == 2'b10) begin
                   r_mul <= i_A * i_B;
                   r_mul_done <= 1;
               end
           end
       end
   end

     always @ (posedge i_clk)
       begin
         if (i_rst)
           begin
             r_mul_1 <= 0;
             r_mul_done2 <= 0;
           end
         else
           begin
             r_mul_1 <= r_mul;
             r_mul_done2 <= r_mul_done;
           end
       end

     always @ (posedge i_clk)
       begin
         if (i_rst)
           begin
             r_D <= 0;
             r_done <= 0;
           end
         else
           begin
             r_D <= r_mul_1;
             r_done <= r_mul_done2;
           end
       end

endmodule
```

Comment: Won't assigning value to r_D in 2 different always loops create problems? 1 assignment is being done for addition in first loop and the 2nd one in last loop. I normally work in VHDL so I am getting this hint from the process style used there.

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem. One way to solve this is to have a different signal for add and mult. Then you could `assign` them to `r_D` depending on the done flag of each of the operation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Assigning based on a flag will lead to a latch, won't it?

Comment: If you use a ternary operator then I think a mux would be inferred. What do you suggest?

Comment: I have not tried using this operator much, I will try this and will update here how it works out :)

Comment: Splitting it up into three flip-flops worked. I was still getting an "unused sequential element" warning but it turned out to be a bug in vivado 2017.1.